# Apply dask QuantileTransformer to a calculated field in the same dataframe

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-ml

I'm trying to apply a dask-ml `QuantileTransformer` transformation to a `percentage` field, and create a new field `percentage_qt` in the same dataframe. But I get the error `Array assignment only supports 1-D arrays`. How to make this work?

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask_ml.preprocessing import QuantileTransformer

mydict = [{'percentage': 12.1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
      {'percentage': 10.2, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 400},
      {'percentage': 11.3, 'b': 2000, 'c': 3000, 'd': 4000 }]
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)

qt = QuantileTransformer(n_quantiles=100)
x = ddf[['percentage']]
y = qt.fit_transform(x)
ddf['percentage_qt'] = y # <-- error happens here
```

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve] so we can actually help you?

Comment: Yes, now you have the complete example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is the following

```sh
ValueError: Array assignment only supports 1-D arrays
```

A `y` is not an array. You could use this trick

Transform `y` to dask dataframe using the same indices as `ddf`

```py
dfy = y.to_dask_dataframe(
    columns=['percentage_qt'],
    index=ddf.index)
```

For some strange reason concat on 0 axis doesn't work (maybe we should open an issue on GH) so we can join the two dataframes as

```py
ddf_out = ddf.join(dfy)
```

Which returns the expected output

```py
print(ddf_out.compute())
```

```sh
   percentage     b     c     d  percentage_qt
0        12.1     2     3     4       1.000000
1        10.2   200   300   400       0.000000
2        11.3  2000  3000  4000       0.656772
```

Comment: I have problems, I think axis should be 1 instead of 0, look at [this](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.multi.concat.html)

Comment: If I set axis=1, I get the following error: `Unable to concatenate DataFrame with unknown division specifying axis=1` where `dfy.known_divisions = False`

Comment: You are right. there are some problems with indices.

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: rpanai, why did you use a join instead of `ddf['percentage_qt'] = dfy['percentage_qt']` ?